# NSDateFormatter sometimes produces 3-digit days and seconds

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

According to my server logs, occasionally iOS will send a weird date like the following:

`2013-08-029T05:15:11.578-0500` (029 as the day)

`2013-09-05T06:43:030.479-0400` (030 as the seconds)

This is my formatter:

```
if (sISO8601Formatter == nil)
{
    // See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html
    sISO8601Formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    if (enUSPOSIXLocale)
        [sISO8601Formatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    sISO8601Formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSZZZ";
}
```

And I format dates like so:

```
+ (NSString *)formatDateWithISO8601:(NSDate *)date forTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone
{
    [sISO8601Formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    return [sISO8601Formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Is this a know bug in iOS or is my formatter wrong? Is it possible it's a threading issue?

Comment: Not that it should be related but your format can be shortened to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ`. You only need to quote literals that could be confused for format specifiers.

Comment: Yeah I went a little crazy trying to rule out a bug with confused format specifiers, but I think the result should be the same.

Comment: Don't see how it could be a threading issue, but you might show us how the formatter is invoked.